# How do I rotate app content?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I already have a good understanding of the OrientationEventListener, and detecting screen orientation. But, how do I rotate or adjust the actual content (buttons, images, tabs, any objects)? Right now, when the user rotates the phone, the content doesn't move or rotate, and it appears sideways to the user.

NOTE: I am using the Droid 2 for testing, and I have noticed that if i I slide out the keyboard, the screen DOES rotate, which is kind of strange in my opinion.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is my code:

```
OrientationEventListener ole = new OrientationEventListener(this) {

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int arg0) {
            TabHost ll = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            try {
            ll.forceLayout();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.exit(0);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    ole.enable();
```

Unfortunately, when the program reaches ll.forceLayout(), it throws a NullPointerException and causes the system to shut down.

SOLVED: I had to edit the manifest such that `android:screenOrientation="sensor"`. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: besides other things you have to declare in which modes your activity can be displayed

Comment: @user788532: Why are you using an orientation listener? If you simply create layouts for both portrait and landscape, Android will automatically switch them for you.

Comment: I was initially thinking of doing that, but I have no idea of how to tell android to switch to the second view when the screen rotates. I assumed it would have something to do with the orientation listener. Plus, since it was adjusting automatically on keyboard slide out, it seemed as though a much easier way was to just figure out how that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I have no idea of how to tell android to switch to the second view
>   when the screen rotates

You don't have to tell it to. If you just create a layout-land folder in your project the system will know to pull layout files from that folder if the device goes in to landscape mode.

Comment: odd... I made the layout-land folder, and placed a main.xml inside it, but when I rotated my device, nothing happened. Is it possible landscape is somehow disabled?

Comment: SOLVED: Apparently, I had to edit the manifest such that `android:screenOrientation="sensor"`, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to call forceLayout () for your root view in the onOrientationChanged.

Comment: Here is a snippet of my code: `TabHost ll = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost); ll.forceLayout();` When the program runs it reaches ll.forceLayout(), but ll.forceLayout produces a NullPointerException.

Comment: Well make sure _ll_ is not null. And post here the stack trace if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave that android:screenOrientation="sensor" out of your manifest. It's the default.

Comment: Thats how it was when it didn't work. I solved my problem by putting it in my manifest.